# Update a dropdown value using workflow rules

Tags: salesforce

I am quite new to salesforce and currently my focus is to understand the workflow rules. My requirement is as follows.

- There is a field called "No Account" which is checkbox type value.
- Then there is another field called "Have an account" which is a picklist and contains "YES" and "NO"
  values.
- If "No Account" checkbox is checked "Have an account" should be updated as "NO" else "YES".

I already tried writing a workflow rule to the above scenario and I can't see any change by activating it.

[image]

Comment: That looks like **validation rule** editor, you sure you know what you're doing? Validation rules are for throwing errors when data is bad, forcing people to match the business logic or cancel. You want to automate changing another field or throw the error?

Comment: @eyescream I want to automate the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make new workflow rule (or process builder if you're more comfortable with that). Actually you might need 2 workflows because you can't use formula to set a picklist's value. If you want to do it with process builder it could have 2 decision nodes (diamond shape), it'd look cleaner.

Make new workflow rule. Pick a good name. Make it run "when created and every time it's edited". Condition set to be based on formula, not criteria. Formula something like `(ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(NoAccount__c)) && NoAccount__c`.
Next make a field update. Select your picklist and set new value. It'll look bit like that:

[image]

Finish, activate the workflow, test it. If it looks good - make another workflow for what should happen when somebody unticks the checkbox. The formula should be `(ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(NoAccount__c)) && !NoAccount__c`. Pick new field update too.